# How to Stream data from/to SQL Server BLOB fields?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

> For the background to this question,
>   see *[“How to I serialize a large
>   graph of .NET object into a SQL Server
>   BLOB without creating a large
>   buffer?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101149/how-to-i-serialize-a-large-graph-of-net-object-into-a-sql-server-blob-without)* that now has a large
>   bounty on it.

I wish to be able to use a [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(VS.71).aspx) object to read/write data to/from a BLOB field in a SQL Server row without having to put the **all** the data into a temp buffer.

---

If the above can be done...

As the Streams class has lot of `CanXXX()` methods, not all streams can be used by all methods take accept stream inputs/outputs.

So how capable does a stream have to be to work with [ADO.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET) when sending data to/from SQL Server?

---

I am looking to have a standard Stream to which I can pass it on to other APIs.

Also the two answers so far only covers getting data form SqlServer, not **sending** the data to SqlServer.

Comment: I arrived at this question when I was searching for the same thing a few days ago. Found complete working solution here: http://www.syntaxwarriors.com/2013/stream-varbinary-data-to-and-from-mssql-using-csharp/

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example for reading data in chunks:

```
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "select somebinary from mytable where id = 1";
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // Read chunks of 1KB
                long bytesRead = 0;
                long dataIndex = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = reader.GetBytes(0, dataIndex, buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    byte[] actual = new byte[bytesRead];
                    Array.Copy(buffer, 0, actual, 0, bytesRead);
                    // TODO: Do something here with the actual variable, 
                    // for example write it to a stream
                    dataIndex += bytesRead;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I am looking to have a standard Stream to I can pass it on to other APIs.

Comment: Actually, it is documented as being ideal to work in chunks of 8040 bytes. I'm also not sure what you are trying to do by copying the buffer each iteration.

Comment: I'm copying the buffer to the `actual` variable depending on the actual bytes read as it may contain less bytes than its size.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't put *all* the data into a buffer; you would typically run a loop, buffering some multiple of 8040 bytes (related to the page size), appending the BLOB each time `WRITETEXT` / `UPDATETEXT` for `image`, or `UPDATE.WRITE` for `varbinary(max)`. [Here's an older example](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/msg/314e7e3782e59a93?pli=1) (uses `image`, sorry).

Likewise, when reading data out you would hopefully be pumping data in a small buffer to some other destination (an http response, a network, a file, etc). Something [like this](http://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/archive.../27/25568.aspx) (although I don't quite like how he handles his EOF / chunking; I'd check +ve bytes read).

Comment: The example read data from a FileStream then reads it to SqlServer, I with have a Stream I can pass to other APIs that write to the Stream and have the data put on the SqlServer

Comment: @Ian - in that case, have you investigated `SqlFileStream` and SQL Server 2008? Perhaps see http://www.aghausman.net/dotnet/saving-and-retrieving-file-using-filestream-sql-server-2008.html

Comment: I don't think we will be able to get all our customers to update to Sql Server 2008, otherwise SqlFileStream would work very well for us.