# Storing large files in database causes An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I've built a small MVC4 web site for sharing files with the code first approach. The files are stored in my database as

```
public byte[] Content { get; set; }
```

Ive set

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="536870912" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

and

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="6000" maxRequestLength="524288"/>
```

To limit filesize to 500 Mb so the file is actually making it into my code (was stuck on this a bit first).

The actual problem is happening when I have received the file and try to save it to the database, I call the:

```
DbContext.SaveChanges()
```

And get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in
>   System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

I'm guessing this is because I am hitting some sort of limit as how much data can be stored in a byte[] in the database (or how much memory my process is allowed to use).. Everything works when uploading smaller files.

The database server is an SQL 2008 R2 Standard server.

I would prefer to avoid storing the files on the disk for sake of simplicity.. what are my options?

**EDIT:** Using the suggestion of doing a straight up SQL query to insert the file got me past the first problem of getting the file into the database:

```
DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    @"UPDATE FileContents
        SET Content = @data 
        WHERE ID = @id",
new SqlParameter("id", content.ID), new SqlParameter("data", bytearray));
```

But I am now getting the exact same error when trying to get the file out of the database instead. This causes the error now:

```
byte[] respdata = DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Byte[]>
                            ("SELECT TOP 1 Content FROM FileContents WHERE ID = @id", 
                            new SqlParameter("id", filepost.File.ID)).Single();
```

Again, it is working for smaller files <100 MB but crashing on 200 Mb files.

Adding stacktrace to question as per a comment in the answers below:

> System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2147024882   Message=Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.   Source=mscorlib
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Object.MemberwiseClone()
>          at System.Array.Clone()
>          at System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbConstantExpression..ctor(TypeUsage
>   resultType, Object value)
>          at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCompiler.GenerateValueExpression(EdmProperty
>   property, PropagatorResult value)
>          at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCompiler.BuildSetClauses(DbExpressionBinding
>   target, PropagatorResult row, PropagatorResult originalRow,
>   TableChangeProcessor processor, Boolean insertMode, Dictionary`2&
>   outputIdentifiers, DbExpression& returning, Boolean& rowMustBeTouched)
>          at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCompiler.BuildInsertCommand(PropagatorResult
>   newRow, TableChangeProcessor processor)
>          at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.TableChangeProcessor.CompileCommands(ChangeNode
>   changeNode, UpdateCompiler compiler)
>          at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.<ProduceDynamicCommands>d__0.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ConcatIterator>d__71`1.MoveNext()
>          at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCommandOrderer..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   commands, UpdateTranslator translator)
>          at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ProduceCommands()
>          at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
>          at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   entityCache)
>          at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
>          at FilePublicator2.Controllers.FileController.Upload(String qqfile) in
>   d:\Projects\FilePublicator2\trunk\FilePublicator2\Controllers\FileController.cs:line
>   115
>          at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult
>   *)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c*_DisplayClass37.<>c_*DisplayClass39.b*_33()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass4f.b*_49()
>   InnerException:

**Solution:**

Here is a complete example of how this was solved:

http://www.syntaxwarriors.com/2013/stream-varbinary-data-to-and-from-mssql-using-csharp/

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx

Comment: How does your entity class look like and what is the datatype of the field in the sql server table?

Comment: What does your current code look like..? could you possibly have a memory leak in your existing code..?

Comment: @rene The datatype in the database is varbinary(max), I have defined it as byte[] in my model.

DJKRAZE I doubt it is a memory leak as it happens on the first request after starting the project, big files always return the error above

Comment: Have you checked the machine's memory usage when the error occurs?

Comment: @DStanley 4 out of 8 GB free when error occurs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`OutOfMemory` has nothing to do with any framework or database. It means that the CLR couldn't allocate an object when asked to.

Probably, you are having the data in multiple buffers like one in an `HttpPostedFile`, one in an in-memory `byte[]`, one in EF, ... This multiplies the amount of memory needed.

Switch to streaming reads from ASP.NET and streaming writes to ADO.NET. Tutorials are available. Search for "SQL Server UPDATE WRITE"

Comment: You are correct in that I'm storing it multiple times, I have it in the HttpPostedFile and in my byte[] array. But if this is the problem wouldent it show itself earlier than untill I'm calling SaveChanges()?

Comment: @JensBerfenfeldt maybe the act of saving causes ADO.NET to create a serialization buffer per row or something. I'd like to see the stack trace, one can guess from that what EF/ADO is doing. Try increasing the file size - you'll see the fault earlier than. The only fix that works for arbitrary file sizes is streaming, though. No way around it.; Btw, if multiple requests come in at the same time memory requirements multiply again. So you cannot guarantee that the app will work without streaming. It might crash randomly.

Comment: Stacktrace added to question. Also rewrote code to use a System.IO.Stream for storing the input stream, I then write the data directly to my model variable byte[]. Same problem persists.

Comment: Looks like a special behavior in EF that causes it to clone the byte[] on insert. My advice is clear now: Stream the data. Nothing else will get you rid of the problem in a sane and permanent way. Btw, I have made the same experience and streaming solved it.

Comment: could you provide an example of how you streamed the data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101346/how-to-stream-data-from-to-sql-server-blob-fields and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046230/streaming-large-file-uploads-to-asp-net-mvc (searching Google for "SQL Server stream bytes" and "ASP.NET stream upload").

Comment: Using those links I built a class that can stream byte arrays to and from the SQL server http://www.syntaxwarriors.com/2013/stream-varbinary-data-to-and-from-mssql-using-csharp/

Comment: @JensBerfenfeldt looks very good! I once did this myself and benchmarked it. Use a bigger buffer, like this: `(1024 * 1024 * 4).RoundUpToMultiple(8040)`. Much faster. (And use CopyTo without async as your Write method does not support async).

Answer (score 2):

You might try bypassing the Entity Framework and using ADO.Net (`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`, etc.) directly.

Comment: If there is no other way I might have to do it this way, would however prefer to use the "standard" EntityFramework way.

Comment: In the end this caused the same problem.