# Streaming a large file into a database BLOB field

Tags: c#, sql-server, stream

I have a large file on disk whose contents I need to store in a SqlServer database as a `VARBINARY(MAX)` field.  By "contents", I mean using something like `File.ReadAllBytes()`.  (I understand the pitfalls of this, but it's the current mode of operations, so I have to deal with it for now.)

I found this answer, which provides a way to stream a large `Byte[]` by using `UPDATE.WRITE`:

[How to I serialize a large graph of .NET object into a SQL Server BLOB without creating a large buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101149/how-to-i-serialize-a-large-graph-of-net-object-into-a-sql-server-blob-without-c/2151491#2151491)

However, simply reading the contents of a large file into a `Byte[]` in memory leads to this problem:

[OutOfMemoryException when I read 500MB FileStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809514/outofmemoryexception-when-i-read-500mb-filestream)

I might be overlooking something obvious, but I just can't work out how should I go about getting from a large file on disk, to the resulting storage into the database.

Comment: Your original title will not help you get answers - it said nothing about what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Gotta chunk it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101346/how-to-stream-data-from-to-sql-server-blob-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some hints I got from these two pages, I have an answer that works:

http://www.syntaxwarriors.com/2013/stream-varbinary-data-to-and-from-mssql-using-csharp/  (this looks a lot like the serialize SO answer, but there's more here...not sure who copied who!).

[How do I copy the contents of one stream to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/how-do-i-copy-the-contents-of-one-stream-to-another?rq=1)

Basically, it uses the same methodology as the answer about serializing Blobs, but instead of using `BinaryFormatter` (a class I'm not fond of anyhow), it creates a `FileStream` that takes the path to the file, and an extension method to copy that stream into the target stream, or `BlobStream`, as the example named it.

Here's the extension:

```
public static class StreamEx
{
    public static void CopyTo(this Stream Input, Stream Output)
    {
        var buffer = new Byte[32768];
        Int32 bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = Input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            Output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

So the trick was to link two streams, copying the data from one to another in chunked fashion, as noted in the comments.