# Is there a SqlFileStream like class that works with Sql Server 2005?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

> For the background to this question,
>   see *[“How to I serialize a large
>   graph of .NET object into a SQL Server
>   BLOB without creating a large
>   buffer?”](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream.aspx)* that now has a large
>   bounty on it.

[SqlFileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream.aspx) gives you an [IoStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) that sits on top of a blob ([varbinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225972(SQL.80).aspx)) value that is stored in the database.   However due to limitations on SqlFileStream implementation it will only work with Sql Server 2008.

Logically I can’t see any reason why the some API cannot be provided on Sql Server 2000 and Sql Server 2005.

- Does anyone know if this has been done?
- Is there an open source implementation of this anywhere?
- What am I missing in thinking it should be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [How to I serialize a large graph of .NET object into a SQL Server BLOB without creating a large buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101149/how-to-i-serialize-a-large-graph-of-net-object-into-a-sql-server-blob-without)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a [SqlFileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream.aspx) class for anything other than SQL Server 2008.  I suspect this is entirely down the fact that the `SqlFileStream` class is specifically designed to "sit on top of" a column of type `FILESTREAM` within SQL Server 2008.

The [`FILESTREAM` column/datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716724.aspx) is only available in SQL Server 2008 and essentially allows large volumes of data to be stored in this column.  A `FILESTREAM` column is actually a `varbinary(max)` column with a `FILESTREAM` modifier.  This essentially causes the SQL Server to effectively bypass the RDBMS storage sub-system and store the binary data directly on the underlying NTFS file system, whist maintaining transactional integrity for this data from the RDBMS perspective.

The [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream.aspx) states this thusly:

> Specifying the FILESTREAM attribute on
>   a varbinary(max) column causes SQL
>   Server to store the data in the local
>   NTFS file system instead of in the
>   database file. Transact-SQL statements
>   provide data manipulation capabilities
>   within the server, and Win32 file
>   system interfaces provide streaming
>   access to the data.

The [FILESTREAM Data in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716724.aspx) MSDN article also states that:

> The SqlFileStream API works in the
>   context of a SQL Server transaction.

But also that:

> SqlFileStream inherits from the
>   System.IO.Stream class, which provides
>   methods for reading and writing to
>   streams of data. Reading from a stream
>   transfers data from the stream into a
>   data structure, such as an array of
>   bytes. Writing transfers the data from
>   the data structure into a stream.

Suggesting that, internally, the SqlFileStream operates in the same manner as a "bog-standard" [`FileStream` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx)

However, perhaps the most telling details as to why this functionality is not available in prior versions of SQL Server (that do not implement any type of FILESTREAM or "direct-to-underlying-storage" column type) is from the [FILESTREAM Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) MSDN article that states:

> FILESTREAM integrates the SQL Server
>   Database Engine with an NTFS file
>   system by storing varbinary(max)
>   binary large object (BLOB) data as
>   files on the file system. Transact-SQL
>   statements can insert, update, query,
>   search, and back up FILESTREAM data.
>   Win32 file system interfaces provide
>   streaming access to the data.
>
> FILESTREAM uses the NT system cache for caching file data. This helps
>   reduce any effect that FILESTREAM data
>   might have on Database Engine
>   performance. The SQL Server buffer
>   pool is not used; therefore, this
>   memory is available for query
>   processing.

This essentially says that using a SqlFileStream object will act almost identically to a "standard" FileStream object, except that SQL Server (for transactional integrity purposes) will act as a very lightweight "gatekeeper" (or "wrapper) for your reading and writing of binary data to an underlying NTFS file system file.  Since no previous version of SQL Server has offered such functionality and direct integration with the underlying NTFS file system, I'd say that it would not be possible to implement a SqlFileStream against any version of SQL Server prior to SQL Server 2008.  (At least not one that has the same "write to a file, but maintain RDBMS transactional integrity" features).

Comment: I don't wish to write to a file, I just wish to be able to use a APIs that need a IOStream to write to, then have the data put into the BLOD one block at a time

Comment: This is a very good description about the internals of SQL server 2008 (hence +1), however the point of a Data Access API is to hide this sort of details.  I am asking about IoStream subclass, there is nothing about the IoStream *contract* that says anything about files at all.  The whole point of base classes like IoStream is to hide the implementation details of different storage systems.  The fact that the IoStream subclass will need to “block” the data before appending the blocks to the blob is only an implementation detail that only it should be interested in.

Answer (score 0):

The FILESTREAM datatype was introduced in SQL Server 2008 and there is no equivalent in SQL Server 2005. This datatype is handled differently than a 'normal' blob type. FILESTREAM data are kept separately to the database as files, while blobs (text or varchar(max) and alike) are kept directly within data pages. So, you can stream contents of files with SqlFileStream in SQL 2008, but to read blobs, db engine has to load them into server memory and return to client as a whole. Because of that it is not possible to have anything like SqlFileStream attached directly to a blob column in SQL 2005.

Comment: As I understood it, SQL Server 2005 can return blobs as blocks and with Ado.net you can request the next block.   Therefore why don't a IOStream subclass sit on top of this?

Comment: I think that database performance-wise it would not be the best option. The blob data would have to reside in the SQL Server's memory. Much better option is to cache the data on client side and stream it from that place. So you would add a business layer between database and clients, perhaps on a web server that would be responsible for streaming.

Comment: I have added a link to the question that give more backround, (our problems are in the cleint not the server.)