# What data type to use for variable length data (for performance)?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, types

What data type should I use for data that can be very short, eg. html link (think twitter), or very long eg. html blog post (think wordpress).

I am thinking if I use `varchar(4000)`, it maybe too short for a html formated blog entry? but if I use `text`, it will take up more space and is less efficient?

### [update]

i am still condering using MySQL (if PHP 5.3/Zend Framework) or MSSQL (if ASP.NET MVC 2)

Comment: Which flavour of database are you using? The performance characteristics of datatype implementations vary from one DBMS to another

Comment: What database?? What version of that database?? Those things vary quite a bit between vendors....

Comment: i am considering MySQL (if using PHP 5.3) and MSSQL (if i use ASP.NET MVC 2)

Comment: to retrieve blob object, it may exceed the buffer size of your database . For this checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101149/how-to-i-serialize-a-large-graph-of-net-object-into-a-sql-server-blob-without-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL also has a `Text` data type for storing an arbitrarily large amount of text. You can find more here: [The BLOB and TEXT Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Micrsoft SQL server 2008 you can use varchar(max).
Edit:
Text is also available but isn't searchable without text indexing..

Comment: ok. i think [MSSQL Server - varchar(max) vs text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834788/ms-sql-server-varcharmax-vs-text "MSSQL Server - varchar(max) vs text") is useful too. what abt if i use MySQL?