# Performances for a Sql Server query or stored procedure to fill lot of data

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, transactions

It is a question for SQL Server 2008 and .NET code.

I am wondering what you think in terms of performances, design between these two options to insert a lot of data (>250,000 rows, 5 “normal” columns) into a table using a transaction.

- a. Insert Into statement surrounded by transact statement in the c# code.

Or

- b. Insert Into statement into a stored procedure executed row-by-row by a while in the c# code surrounded by a transact statement.

Or

- c. Serialize my object in c# and send the xml to a stored procedure. The stored procedure is a while what read the xml. The while is surrounded by a transact statement.

Also, the network between the client and the server is not very good...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already take care of batch commit, the next issue is going to be the round trips back-and-forth to the client. The fewer requests, the better. So first two options would be pretty bad, since each sends one row per request and have to round-trip 250k times. Option 3 is viable, specially if the XML processing is set oriented (project the XML into a table via [.nodes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) method and insert the entire projected table). See also [How to I serialize a large graph of .NET object into a SQL Server BLOB without creating a large buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101149/how-to-i-serialize-a-large-graph-of-net-object-into-a-sql-server-blob-without/2151491#2151491) for a trick on how to send a large XML to SQL w/o huge memory allocations on client.

The other option you did not mention but was already pointed out: use [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx). This would be the fastest way due to many reasons. Only gotcha is that you must endure a way to present the rows to be bulk copied usign streaming semantics (yield return of a IEnumerable) , to avoid large memory allocations in the client.

Answer (score 2):

As always you should profile your code but I'd recommend you look into using the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class.

Comment: +1 this is the fastest way to insert many rows of data, it is .NET way of executing the bcp command or BULK INSERT statement for SQL

Comment: Yes you right, I didn't thought of the SqlBulkCopy. I don't have the habit to use this command.