# T-SQL Poor performance when concatenating a large string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My C# application calls a stored procedure that includes the following `UPDATE` statement to concatenate a `VARCHAR(max)` column with the string `@input` that is passed in as a parameter:

```
UPDATE [TblTest] 
SET [txtData] = [txtData] + @input
WHERE [TblTestID] = @id
```

`@input` will typically have a length of a million characters.

The stored procedure is called multiple times. As the length of the string stored in `txtData` column increases, the performance of the `UPDATE` statement degrades considerably. E.g. it takes over 30 seconds to execute when `txtData` has over 300 million characters, with just a single record in the table.

Are there any options available to optimise the SQL to improve performance? I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well it has to write 300 million characters to disk. Why do you need to store that much data in a single tuple?

Comment: You might consider storing the values in the file system and just keeping a filename for the reference.  That is a lot of data.

Comment: is `TblTestID` the primary key of `TblTest`?, you are concatenating a big chunk of data though

Comment: `SET [txtData] = [txtData] + @input` might transfer more than 300MB for a single record (read data, concatenate, write back). If I not mistaken, SQL is not really meant for fast string operations. What are actually storing there? Can't you break the information?

Comment: That is really kind of an absurd of amount of information. The entire king james bible has about 3.5 million letters. You are storing nearly 100 copies of the entire bible as a single string. Of course it is going to be slow.

Comment: @SeanLange Agree. `TblTest` caches the results of a request to a (poorly designed) legacy web service. Subsequent requests read from this table instead of the source data. Previously the results were added to this table as single insert (which was much quicker), however in order to reduce the memory footprint in the C# app, the results are now processed in chunks. I may consider storing the chunks in separate rows to avoid concatenating, or perhaps store in the file system as suggested above. The answers given below sound really promising and may offer me a quicker fix (using `WRITE` syntax).

Comment: @Lamak yes `TblTestID` is the primary key of `TblTest`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having a performance problem so start investigating it as such. Read and follow [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/).

Your problem could be from a missing index on `[TblTestId]`, it could be caused by log or database growth % factor blockage, it could be your client side code slowing down as memory grows and passing in parameters slower and slower, it could be from not using the WRITE syntax for updating BLOBs (`UPDATE ... SET txtData.WRITE ...`) and so on and so forth. Only by **measuring** will you be able to find the cause.

Comment: Also this old answer can contain some valuable information for your case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2151491/105929

Comment: Both yours and Alexei's answers helped me resolved this issue, by using the `WRITE` syntax. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `UPDATE` with `.WRITE (expression,@Offset,@Length)` ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)).

According to [this source](http://sqlsolace.blogspot.ro/2013/01/update-write-sql-2012.html), this is a fast way to update large columns:

> A traditional UPDATE statement is logged Using the .WRITE clause is
>   minimally logged (faster)
>
> If @Offset is NULL, the update operation appends expression at the end
>   of the column.

In your case, try this:

```
UPDATE [TblTest] 
SET column.WRITE(@input, NULL, 1)  -- length is ignored
WHERE [TblTestID] = @id
```